# Остановить все Windows службы, не содержащихся в списке

Tags: c#, windows-service

Останавливаю службы из списка `List<string>` таким способом:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication25 {
    class Program {
        static List<string> services = new List<string> {
            "AdobeARMService", "RemoteRegistry", "TermService", "Messenger", "SSDPSRV"
        };
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Run());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Run() {
            while (true) {
                var temp = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(s => services.Contains(s.ServiceName)).ToList();
                temp.ForEach(t => {
                    try {
                        t.Stop();
                    }
                    catch { }
                });
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А как сделать обход служб в `List<string> services` ? чтобы их не останавливал, а все остальные службы которых нету в списке остановить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень опасно останавливать все службы... Но хозяин барин...

```
public async Task<bool> StopAllServicesExcept(params string[] exceptServices)
{
    var servicesToStop = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(s => !exceptServices.Contains(s.ServiceName));
    var tasks = servicesToStop.Select(s => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            s.Stop();
            s.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    })).ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return tasks.All(t => t.Result);
}
```

Что тут происходит:

- Берем все сервисы и вычеркиваем из списка все, которые останавливать не надо.
- Создаем кучу тасков, которые стопают сервисы (поставил таймаут 1 мин, если за это время не стопнулся сервис - скорее всего что-то пошло не так и смысла ждать нет, по видимому...). Они возвращают `true` в случае успешного стопа, иначе - `false`.
- Ждем выполнения всех тасков.
- Возвращаем `true`, если все сервисы стопнулись успешно, иначе - `false`.

Вызывать из асинхронной функции просто:

```
var allServicesStopped = await StopAllServicesExcept("Service1", "Service2");
```

Если вызывать из `Main`:

```
var task = StopAllServicesExcept("Service1", "Service2");
task.Wait();
var allServicesStopped = task.Result;
```

Comment: Опасно это да, но в списке будут находиться все самые нужные службы для работы системы. Попробую Ваш способ

Comment: @ArteS чуть добавил описания по тому что происходит в методе. Скажите, а почему бы просто не стопать ваш список сервисов, почему именно "все,кроме"?

Comment: Я подумал запихнуть в список только системные (важные для системы) службы, а все остальные в степени необходимости завершить. А вызывать его так-же? Как его вызывать?

Comment: @ArteS такое чувство, будто вы со всякими надоедливыми мейл.ру и яндекс спамом боретесь :)

Comment: так а как его вызывать правильно?

Comment: @ArteS как и любые асинхронные методы. Обновил ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61070/discussion-between-artes-and-ags17).